# WebView visibility issue in Layout in Android

Tags: android, layout, webview

I do not understand Android layouts. I have the following structure and have tried all sorts of combinations of Relative and Linear layouts with layout above, below, gravity etc. and no matter what I do the webview either disappears or pushes the buttons off the bottom of the screen.

I do not understand why the renderer thinks this way. Surely if you have other things in the layout it should adjust it accordingly?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/cage" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/homelinklayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TextView android:text="FRAMTIDS" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/hometext1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"></TextView>
        <TextView android:text="GYMNASIET" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/hometext2" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"></TextView>
        <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/homeimage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/next"></ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/homewebviewlayout"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" >
            <WebView android:id="@+id/webview" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/homebuttons" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:src="@drawable/icon_mapsetup" android:id="@+id/btn_skolor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="bottom"></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_mapsetup" android:id="@+id/btn_program"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="bottom"></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_mapsetup" android:id="@+id/btn_framtid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="bottom"></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_mapsetup" android:id="@+id/btn_kontakt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="bottom"></ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very sure what you are trying to do here but try this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/cage"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView android:text="FRAMTIDS" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/hometext1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"></TextView>
        <TextView android:text="GYMNASIET" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/hometext2" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"></TextView>
        <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/homeimage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/next"></ImageView>

            <WebView android:id="@+id/webview" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/homebuttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
      >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_skolor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/capture" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_program"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn_skolor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_mapsetup" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_framtid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_below="@id/btn_program"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_mapsetup" >
        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_kontakt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn_framtid"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_mapsetup" >
        </ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

you will be able to see your views